# How to get a spanning set from two sets as follows

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have an inner product space $V$ and there exists two sets $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_i\}$ such that for all $x$ $\in V$:

$$\sum_i v_i \langle w_i,x\rangle =x$$

how do we construct a new set, $z_i$ (of not necessarily the same cardinality)  from these $v_i$ and $w_i$, such that for all $x\in V$? $$\sum_i z_i \langle z_i,x\rangle =x$$

I am trying to generalise this for C*-algebra valued inner products so I would like this to be just an algebraic construction using the equations above. I tried to just sub in the first equation for $x=w_i$ but it doesnt seem to help.

Comment: Write `\langle` and `\rangle` to get the brackets for inner products, rather than `<` and `>`, which are symbols for less than and greater than.

Comment: Clearly the set $\{v_{i}\}$ already generates $V$, so to find a basis you only have to get rid of linear dependency and orthogonalise.

Comment: Right, my problem here and hence why i commented I need to do it algebraically from these formulas is that I can not do Gramm-Schmidt in the setting I want as the inner product is <u,v> has values in a C* algebras which may not be invertible and so I can not divide by it.